# Implicit differentiation of the form $f(x,y) - 5 = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I have been learning about implicit differentiation and so far I have not much trouble when I am given an equation where I can see the variables explicitly (like $x^2+y^2-1 = 0$). However, I have stumbled upon a problem that has me stuck for too long now and would like some guidance. Here it goes

Suppose $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function defined in the open set $U$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous at the point $(-1,2)$. Furthermore suppose that $f(-1,2) = 5$ and $\frac{\partial f(-1,2)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f(-1,2)}{\partial x} > 0$. I am asked the following:

a) To show that $f(x,y) = 5$ defines implicitly the functions $x=\phi(y)$ and $y=\psi(x)$ in the vicinity of $(-1,2)$

b) To calculate $\phi'(-1)\psi'(2)$.

Setting $F(x,y) = f(x,y) -5$, I was able to verify part a) using the implicit function theorem. However, I am stuck at b). Normally I would go on by calculating the total differential of $F$, that is

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}F &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y = 0 \\
\mathrm{d}F &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \psi}\frac{\mathrm{d} \psi}{\mathrm{d} x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} x}\mathrm{d}y = 0
\end{align}
$$

But that's it I am afraid. I don't know how to use the information provided to say something about the partial derivatives of $f$ i.e., I would normally be able to calculate them and solve for the desired derivative, but I can't proceed that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note 
$$x=\phi(y)\Rightarrow 1=\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\phi(y)=\phi'(y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
and $$y=\psi(x)\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)=\psi'(x)$$
From these two equations you obtain
$$1=\phi'(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=\phi'(y)\psi'(x)$$
So for $(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(-1,2)$ we have $\phi'(y)\psi'(x)=1$. In particular $\phi'(2)\psi'(-1)=1$.

Comment: That did it for me, thank you very much! I can see now that I did not quite understand what it meant to have $x=\phi(y)$ and $y=\psi(x)$